# Error while streaming MJPEG video with RTSP protocol

Tags: c++, opencv, gstreamer

I want to stream a MJPEG video from my ethernet camera with OpenCV and Gstreamer. 
I have tried to open the stream with the following gstreamer pipeline:

```
std::string pipe( 
                "rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.1.219:554/video.pro1 ! application/x-rtp,encoding-name=JPEG,payload=26 ! " 
                "rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! xvimagesink sync=false ! appsink" 
        ); 
cv::VideoCapture cap(pipe, cv::CAP_GSTREAMER);
```

but the previous code returns me the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (GStreamer: cannot find appsink in manual pipeline 
) in cvCaptureFromCAM_GStreamer, file /home/nvidia/Documents/CameraTests/src/opencv-3.3.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line 796 
VIDEOIO(cvCreateCapture_GStreamer (CV_CAP_GSTREAMER_FILE, filename)): raised OpenCV exception: 

/home/nvidia/Documents/CameraTests/src/opencv-3.3.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:796: error: (-2) GStreamer: cannot find appsink in manual pipeline 
 in function cvCaptureFromCAM_GStreamer
```

I managed to stream the the same RTSP source with H264 and H265 algorithms, 
MJPEG is the only format that doesn't work, then I suppose that is a gstreamer pipeline problem..

thanks

Comment: You have two sinks in your pipeline. Is that want you wanted? Just wondering what the `appsink` is supposed to accomplish here. And its the part that throws the error too..

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have tried to remove "appsink" at the end of the pipeline, but the error is the same..

Comment: mjpg is a tricky streaming format, probably it isn't implemented correctly in either gstreamer of opencv VideoCapture. Some Servers send full jpg images, but the MJPG streaming standard tells to not send the full header for each frame. For example, VLC Videoplayer can not receive correctly streamed MJPG stream (but it can stream wrong-streamed full-image-jpgs). Once I had to implement a live555 streaming server and client and had some struggle with that format :) You could try VLC and the live555 test-client whether one of them, or both can receive your stream.

Comment: I don't know opencv - but it complains it cannot find `appsink`. Probably it wants to hook into its callbacks to import the data that arrives there - you probably want to remove the `xvimagesink` but keep the `appsink`? Or if you want to have both add a `tee`. I guess the opencv manual covers that topic?